# Is it possible to link directly to Google search results using href?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, search-engine

I would like to link directly to a search results page from a standard link. To give an example of what I'm hoping for, here is some pseudocode:

```
<a href = "https://www.google.com/search?keywords=My+Search+Parameters">Click here to search Google</a>
```

Is there any way to do this? I would like to redirect my users directly to a search results page so they can see real results on the web.

Comment: [https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+link+directly+to+google+search+results](https://www.google.fi/search?q=how+to+link+directly+to+google+search+results)

Comment: ^ Such a meta response. +1

Comment: If I had the rep to upvote the first comment, I would. Thanks!

Comment: How about search for a specific hastag? per example https://www.google.com/search?q=#ExampleTag , wont work, it returns an empty search

Comment: @Pluda you'll need to URL-escape the query - the `#` is interpreted as a document fragment, not a literal hash symbol. The working link would be [google.com/search?q=%23ExampleTag](https://www.google.com/search?q=%23ExampleTag).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please have a look at the link below:

http://www.googleguide.com/linking.html

```
<a href=”http://www.google.com/search?q=Google+tutorial+create+link”>
   Google tutorial create link
</a>
```

Comment: Alright, well, that was apparently an obvious question. Thanks for the quick answer!